# Solr: how to handle boolean operators and hyphens?

Tags: solr

For example, let's say the user enters the query: `2-surface AND filling`

The tokenizer will split the hyphenated word, and the query will not have the intended effect (the intended effect of the user was probably `2 AND surface AND filling`. What's the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: Use a tokenizer that doesn't split on `-`?

Comment: I guess that's the only way. If I do that though, alot of hyphenated searches will not produce the desired matches. I'm also using the standard tokenizer because I was having trouble using WordDelimiterGraphFilter together with SynonymGraphFilter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120979/solr-is-there-a-reason-why-synonymgraphfilter-must-come-before-worddelimitergra

Comment: Use multiple fields and boost those with a more stringent tokenizer a higher boost - in effect scoring those documents that match exactly higher and returning them at the top of the search result.

Comment: Cool solution, thank you!